# Stripe Api call Generate double Invoice on Firebase cloud function call

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Why when i call this function Stripe generate 2 invoice?

I want to set a custom price % for the invoice and not using a fixed price as suggested on the documentation.
I want that the invoice is automatically payed by the customer.

```
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    let data = request.body;
    
    var imponibile = 100;
    const { stripe } = require("./stripe");
    const { db } = require("./admin");

    const invoiceItem = await stripe.invoiceItems.create({
      customer: data.customerId,
      description: data.description,
      amount: imponibile,
      currency: "eur",
    });

    const invoice = await stripe.invoices.create({
      customer: data.customerId,
      auto_advance: true, // Auto-finalize this draft after ~1 hour
      collection_method: "charge_automatically",
    });

    const payinvoice = await stripe.invoices.pay(invoice.id);
    return payinvoice;
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you please check your cloud function logs if this function is triggered twice?

Comment: Yes the function is triggered twice, but i disable the button that call the function on click

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the problem was that i was returning the actual payment function recursively.

Solution :

```
return respond.status(200).send('ok')
```